# Do you see any issues with this GetData script for SharePoint?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

I have included the JS and HTML script to see if anyone may see issues with these scripts? They are for a SharePoint list and both files are stored in a site asset library.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>     

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/GetData.js"></script>    
    <!--External js file to get data from SharePoint List -->   

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.20/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">      
</head>    
<body>    
   <div>    
    <table id="table_id" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">    
        <thead>    
            <tr>    
                <th>Name</th>    
                <th>Position</th>    
                <th>Office</th>    
                <th>Age</th>    
                <th>Joining Date</th>            
            </tr>    
        </thead>    
        <tfoot>  
            <tr>    
                <th>Name</th>    
                <th>Position</th>    
                <th>Office</th>    
                <th>Age</th>    
                <th>Joining Date</th>                   
            </tr>   
        </tfoot>    
    </table>    
    </div>    
</body>    
</html>    

<!--GetData JS script below-->

function loadItems() {    

var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;    

var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfoTest')

/items?$select=Title,Position,Office,Age,Joining_x0020_Date";  

    $.ajax({    
        url: oDataUrl,    
        type: "GET",    
        dataType: "json",    
        headers: {    
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"    
        },    
        success: mySuccHandler,    
        error: myErrHandler    
    });    
}   
function mySuccHandler(data) {    
    try {    

        $('#table_id').DataTable({    

            "aaData": data.d.results,    
            "aoColumns": [  
            {    
                "mData": "Title"    
            },   
            {    
                "mData": "Position"    
            },   
            {    
                "mData": "Office"    
            },   
            {    
                "mData": "Age"    
            },  
            {    
                "mData": "Joining_x0020_Date"    
            }             
            ]    
        });    
    } catch (e) {    
        alert(e.message);    
    }    
}  
function myErrHandler(data, errMessage) {    
    alert("Error: " + errMessage);    
}
```

The first portion is the HTML page, and then the second part of the script is the JS. I have commented out where the JS script starts.

Here is the output I get in SharePoint-image below:

[GetData output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9LAG.jpg)

Comment: are you calling your function in $(document).ready(function(){}); ?

Answer (score 0):

well error is hard to find but still u have missed out few steps when starting with js

this link i have sent will help u out
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-jquery-datatable-to-display-sharepoint-list-data-on-share/

Comment: What JS files did I miss?  I added them to the script? Should they be downloaded and added to the site library?

Comment: yes i feel thats what i felt when i compared the codes @AlexL. check the steps that i have shared its clearly given

Comment: Not sure with what your saying.  The steps were not clear. Should I download the JS/CSS file and save them to site assets?

Comment: Oh Ok, so change the script location from CDN and reference the site assets library with the saved JS/CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find where you call the function `loadItems`, I load SharePoint list data after DOM ready usually as `_spPageContextInfo` depends on SharePoint JS libraries init(so _spPageContextInfo may not init correctly if you use it if you not delay your rest request ).

Sample demo:

```
<table id="example" class="wpDataTable" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>TestNumber</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>TestNumber</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listtitle')/items?$select=Title,City,TestNumber&$orderby=Created",
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (result) {
                    _Data = result.d.results;

                    $('#example').DataTable({
                        columns: [
                            { "data": "Title" },
                            { "data": "City" },
                            { "data": "TestNumber" }
                        ],
                        data: _Data,
                        "displayLength": 25
                    })
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
```